# What is the center of power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

The power series is: 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x+4)^n}{n+1}
$$

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "center"?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really understand what it meant either, I think it's asking for the radius.

Comment: In my reading, the center is at $x=-4$.

Comment: Yup, the center is $x =-4$. Given a power series, $\sum a_n(x-a)^n$ is centered about $a$.

Comment: could either @Berci or MathNewbie 48 write it out as an answer, because I'd like to give you the 'best answer' vote!

Answer (score 5):

From *Calculus: 8th Edition* by Larson:

> [A]n infinite series of the form
>
> $$ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$$
>
> is called a **power series centered at *c*,** where *c* is a constant.

So here $c = -4$.